# Exclude URL from mobile redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a mobile redirect based off of user agents.  I now want to exclude one page.  I read in another question that I should do the following, but the Nice_page.html still redirects to the mobile site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|#opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Nice_page.html [NC]

RewriteRule .* http://example.mobile.com/ [R]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: (off-topic) Your rewrite rule reminded me this: http://xkcd.com/869/

Comment: Your link is like `http://www.domain.com/nice_page.html` ? Without directory ?

Comment: Yes, it is just http://www.domain.com/nice_page.html

Comment: Why guess when there's a rewritelog / LogLevel rewrite:trace8

Comment: I dont know know what that means, can you elaborate?